# Join in LINQ Query Syntax: moving right side to the left

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

I have a scenario where I need to join two tables:

A

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        John      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        Matt      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |        Emma      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

B

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Text      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |  blah blah John  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          | this is some data|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          | My name is Jeff  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I need to use LINQ's query syntax to join these two tables.

The left table needs to be Table A.

Though I need to join based on whether the "text" column contains the text from the Name column in Table A.

The code should look something like this:

```
var result = from ta in A
             join tb in B on tb.Text.Contains(ta.Name)
```

I can't seem to use `tb` on the left side of the join.

I can only use `ta`.

`tb` works on the right side of the join.

Is there any way I can switch it around, so that I'm able to use `tb` on the left side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joins in LINQ can work only with equality matching. But you could use `SelectMany` method combined with `Where`. It will essentially do a join by condition.

In query syntax, it would be like this:

```
from ta in A
from tb in B
where tb.Text.Contains(ta.Name)
// the rest of your query
```

See also [Perform custom join operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations)